# Duda Formulario PHP

Tags: php

Hola a toda la comunidad, Tengo una simple duda, ¿Que es mejor poner el codigo PHP de un formulario dentro del mismo formulario o crear otro Archivo donde este el codigo PHP que va a procesar el formulario?

Comment: Es mejor que crees un archivo a parte que contenga el código php

Comment: Hola Pedro, bienvenido a StackOverflow. En este sitio las preguntas cuya respuesta no es objetiva (basada en opiniones) no son bien vistas. En tu caso, la pregunta "Es mejor", llama a este tipo de respuestas. ¿Es mejor para quién?. Puedes mejorar tu pregunta siendo más específico, por ejemplo, puede ser que te preocupe el rendimiento del sitio, o la seguridad, etc. Si eres más específico en tu pregunta y la haces de manera que las respuestas puedan ser objetivas, no dudo que obtendrás la respuesta que buscas. Te invito a leer [que preguntas evitar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Creo que en este caso se puede dar una opinión objetiva sobre la pregunta.

Comment: Hola Pedro como he visto que has añadido una respuesta para agradecer: no pongas respuestas para agradecer. Las respuestas deben de ser para ayudar a resolver la pregunta, no para agradecer a nadie. Si quieres agradecer a alguien dale voto positivo y acepta la pregunta que te parezca más adecuada. ¡Ojo! Esto no es una bronca. Yo también fui nuevo en esto y también puse respuestas para agradecer hasta que alguien me dijo que no se hacía así. Un saludo y espero que disfrutes del sitio :)

Answer (score 3):

Según las recomendaciones de [estilo php](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/), lo correcto es mantener, digámoslo así, la lógica separada de las vistas. Por lo tanto, es mejor que mantengas el formulario separado del código que lo procesa. Puedes leer esta y otras recomendaciones aquí: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#2-3-side-effects

Answer (score 2):

Como te han comentado por pura organización es mejor mantenerlos en ficheros diferentes.

Imagina que necesitas modificar algo de la lógica PHP, es más fácil leer el código en un fichero único PHP que en uno donde esté todo el entramado HTML & PHP.

Además de cara a corregir incidencias en el código también es aconsejable tenerlo separado.

Pero puede ser que por comodidad a lo mejor a ti te venga mejor tenerlo todo en uno, por lo que tampoco hay una respuesta de blanco o negro en este asunto.

Answer (score 0):

Para mí es mucho mejor separar la parte de servidor (php) con la parte del cliente (el formulario). ¿Por qué? Si separas la lógica por un lado (php) de la presentación (html) es mucho más fácil mantener el código que si lo tienes todo junto. Además, es mucho más fácil leer el código.